# Simple knockout code not working in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am having trouble testing knockout in js fiddle.... I believe I have it setup correctly  but the results are not correct. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevison/owxy54kg/) to what I am working on... just trying to do basic data-binding.

html code:

```
name <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
<p>
  Hi there <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</p>
```

knockout:

```
$(function() {
   var viewModel = {
      name: "Edgar"
     };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

The output doesnt show the name... cant figure out why.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Open the dev tools and checkout the error

Comment: Did the console of the browser showing any error

Comment: @HakamFostok - no it didnt show any error... which was really annoying.  I should have opened the dev tools.  That might have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't see any issue in code

update fiddle to different CDN - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/knockout 
and add jquery CDN https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js

updated fiddle

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jituce/owxy54kg/17/)

```
  $(function() {
   var viewModel = {
      name: "Edgar"
   };

   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: Thank you... I thought that selecting the jquery library would only require me to add the knockout CDN. My mistake!  thank you again!